# From Compiler to assembler

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

I have a question regarding the assembler. I was thinking of how the C function that takes multiple parameters as an argument is transformed into assembly. So my question is, is there a subroutine in assembly that takes arguments as a parameter to operate?
The code might look something like this:

Call label1, R16.
Where R16 is the subroutine input parameter.

If that's not the case then that means that EACH time the C function is called, it gets assembled into a subroutine with the parameters related to the specific call being substituted automatically in it. That basically means that whenever a C function is called, the compiler transforms it into an inline function which am sure is not the case either :D

So which is right?
Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Hopefully the following links are useful to your question: [CToAssemblyTranslation](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Basics/CToAssemblyTranslation.htm#.VqiDKpebgsY). [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames).

Comment: *Which* assembly? x86's `call` is just a "jump that remembers where it came from", zero parameters are involved, you just pass them however you want.

Comment: _"If that's not the case then that means"_ that parameters are either placed in registers prior to the call instruction, or on the stack. It depends on which cpu architecture you're programming for, and which calling convention you're using.

Comment: In  x86 the parameters are stored on a stack. Read about ebp and esp registers (they are used to assign memory for function arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler uses a "calling convention" which can be specific to that one compiler for that one target architecture (x86, arm, mips, pdp-11, etc).  For architectures with "plenty" of general purpose registers, the calling convention often starts with passing parameters in registers, and then uses the stack, for architectures with not a lot of registers the stack is primarily if not completely used for parameter passing and the return.

The calling convention is a set of rules, such that if everyone follows the rules you can compile functions into objects and link them with other objects and they will be able to call each others functions or call themselves.

So it is a bit of a hybrid of what you were assuming.  The code built for that function is in some respects custom to that function as the number and type of parameters dictate what registers or how much stack is consumed and how.  At the same time all functions conform to the same formula so they look more alike than different.

On an arm for example you might have three integers being passed in to a function, they would for all the arm calling conventions I have seen (generally you find that even though it could vary across compilers it often doesnt or in the case of arm and mips and some others they try to dictate the convention for everyone rather than the compiler folks trying to do it) the first parameter in the C function would come in in r0, the second in r1 and third in r2.  If the first parameter were a 64 bit integer though then r0 and r1 are used for that first parameter and r2 gets the second and r3 the third, after r3 you use the stack, ordering of parameters on the stack is also dictated by the convention.  So when a caller or a callee's code is compiled using the same C prototype then both sides know exactly where to find the parameters and construct the assembly language to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some minimal options in some instruction sets, but in general that is not the case.

Some assemblers have macros though that mimic procedural calls (usually with only a few registrable basetypes).

And no, only in the case of inline functions a new function is generated with the parametrised with the parameters substituted.

A compiler doesn't generate code for a procedure by textual substitution of parameters, but by putting all relevant parameters in registers or on the stack in a fixed regime called the "calling convention".

The code that calculates and loads the parameters (in registers or on stack) is generated for each invocation, and the procedure/function remains unmodified and loads the parameters from where it knows it can find them